# Splunk Alert on missing log with GUID

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to create a Splunk alert that will be triggered if two events do not occur in a certain time window. The two events will be linked by a GUID and there may be multiple events occurring with different GUIDs simultaneously.

Can someone indicate where to start?

Answer (score 1):

There probably are a few ways to do this.  The worst one is by using the `transaction` command because it's very slow.

Try using `stats` to find the time span of the events and alert on those that are too slow (5 minutes in this example).

```
... | stats range(_time) as duration by GUID | where duration > 300
```